# Why does ruby spawn double the processes that I fork?

Tags: ruby, tcp, process, network-programming, fork

The following exhibits the forking code. This is a very minimal application just to play around with TCP and FTP.

```
require 'socket'
require_relative '../lib/ftp/common'

module FTP
  class Preforking
    include Common

    CONCURRENCY = 4

    def run
      child_pids = []

      CONCURRENCY.times do
        child_pids << spawn_child
      end

      trap(:INT) {
        child_pids.each do |c|
          begin
            Process.kill(:INT, c)
          rescue Errno::ESRCH
          end
        end

        exit
      }

      loop do
        pid = Process.wait
        $stderr.puts "Process #{pid} quit unexpectedly"

        child_pids.delete(pid)
        child_pids << spawn_child
      end
    end

    def spawn_child
      fork do
        loop do
          @client = @control_socket.accept
          respond "220 OHAI"

          handler = CommandHandler.new(self)

          loop do
            request = @client.gets(CRLF)
            if request
              respond(handler.handle(request))
            else
              @client.close
              break
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Because of the value of FTP::Preforking::CONCURRENCY, I'd expect 5 processes total. The main process and 4 child processes.

Running the application with a call to run generates the following in htop:
[image: htop]

What's interesting to me is that this is exactly double the number of processes than I expect.

Any hints on why this is happening?

For the interested, the full application is here: https://github.com/Senjai/Learning-Ruby/tree/master/mini-projects/ftp